# Isotopy between arithmetic mean and geometric mean

Tags: general-topology, means

Is there / could we define an isotopy within $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R_+}^n)$ from the arithmetic mean to the geometric mean or even the harmonic mean?
I recently saw the AM-GM inequality and got catched by the question.

Comment: The logarithm of the geometric mean is the arithmetic mean of the logarithms of its arguments .  The inverse of the harmonic mean is the arithmetic mean of the inverse of its arguments.

Comment: 1) What do you call an iso**topy** ? 2) Logarithm function gives a group iso**morphism** $\ln: \mathbb R_+^* \to \mathbb R$ sending the GM(a,b) onto the $AM(\ln a,\ln b)$